# How does R calculate parameters of MA model？

Tags: arima

How does R calculate parameters of MA model？ What is the algorithm?

In wikipedia, it is said Fitting the MA estimates is more complicated than with autoregressive models (AR models) because the lagged error terms are not observable. This means that iterative non-linear fitting procedures need to be used in place of linear least squares.

Comment: "How does R..." is very software specific and not generally on-topic here (see our [help/on-topic]), you are usually best to ask the people who make the software or in a software-specific forum. Having said that, for R you can just look directly at the source code to see what it is doing. Do you want to know specifically how the R functions work, or are you interested in MA fitting in general? In the latter case I suggest you drop the specific reference to R.

Comment: Did you read the help? `?arima` under the entry for the `method` argument says that by default it uses ML starting at parameter values obtained by minimizing conditional sum of squares. Additional details are in the section labelled "*Fitting methods*", which describe using a KF algorithm to evaluate the likelihood. There are references in the help, including to the paper by Gardner, Harvey and Phillips.

Comment: Thanks, I read the help. But it is not very explicit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of fitting MA model in R, namely *arma* function from package **tseries**, *arima0*  and *arima* functions from package **stats**, and *Arima* from package **forecast** (this function is basically a wrapper for *arima*). All these functions can fit more general models than MA, namely ARMA and ARIMA.

Function *arma* uses conditional least squares method, *arima0* uses maximum likelihood and *arima* and *Arima* lets to choose between those two methods or to use their combination, i.e. find initial parameter values by CSS and then apply ML, this is the default option.

More details about the exact algorithms can be found in the help pages for these functions and naturally their code.

Both conditional least squares and maximum likelihood methods in case of general ARIMA model are non-linear iterative fitting procedures.

Comment: Thanks, so it starts from an estimated model?